# MS Access SQL: select rows with the same order as IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-order-by, in-clause

I know that this question has been asked several times and I've read all the answer but none of them seem to completely solve my problem.

I'm switching from a mySQL database to a MS Access database. In both of the case I use a php script to connect to the database and perform SQL queries.

I need to find a suitable replacement for a query I used to perform on mySQL.
I want to:

1. perform a first query and order records alphabetically based on one of the columns
2. construct a list of IDs which reflects the previous alphabetical order
3. perform a second query with the IN clause applied with the IDs' list and ordered by this list.

In mySQL I used to perform the last query this way:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN ($name_ids) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,'$name_ids')
```

Since `FIND_IN_SET` is available only in mySQL and `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX` are not available from my php script, how can I achieve this?

I know that I could write something like:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM users 
 WHERE id IN ($name_ids) 
ORDER BY CASE id
           WHEN ... THEN 1 
           WHEN ... THEN 2
           WHEN ... THEN 3
           WHEN ... THEN 4
         END
```

but you have to consider that:

- IDs' list has variable length and elements because it depends on the first query
- that list can easily contains thousands of elements

Have you got any hint on this?
Is there a way to programmatically construct the `ORDER BY CASE ... WHEN ...` statement?
Is there a better approach since my list of IDs can be big?

**UPDATE:** I perform two separated query because I need to access two different tables.
The databse it's not very simple so I try to make an example:
Suppose I have a table which contains a list of users and a table which contains all the books that every user have in their bookshelf.

Since the dabase was designed in mySQL, for every book record I store the user_id in the books table in order to have a relationship between the user and the book.

Suppose now that I want to obtain a list of all the user that have books with a title starting with letter 'a' and I want to order the user based on the alphabetical oder of the books.
This is what I do:

1. perform a first query to find all the books which start with letter 'a' and sort the alphabetically
2. create a list of user_id which should reflect the alphabetical order of the book
3. perform a query in the users table to find out the users names and sort them with the user_id list to have the required sorting by book

Hope this clarify what I need.

Comment: Do these have to be two seperate queries?  What does the first one look like?  It's completely possible that things could be improved by combining them, or rethinking how they're connected.

Comment: They are separate queries because are performed on two separate tables. I'll edit the question to clarify this aspect

Comment: What, and the two tables can't be `JOIN`ed?  What's the name and layout of that first table?

Comment: @X-Zero: I've updated the question with an example. Probably there was an easier way to construct the database but I've only a little experience in SQL and database in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a `JOIN`...
This *should* work, although it may need to be translated to Access syntax (which is apparently subtly different):

```
SELECT b.name, a.title
FROM book as a
JOIN user as b
ON b.id = a.userId
WHERE SUBSTRING(LOWER(a.title), 1, 1) = 'a'
ORDER by a.title
```

I don't know why you're switching to Access, although I have heard it's been improving in recent years.  I think I'd prefer almost any other RDBMS, though.  And your schema could probably stand some tweaking, from the sound of things.

Comment: It wasn't a decision of mine, we moved our website to a new server in a new location and this new server farm provides Access only as database support.
I'd prefer mySQL without any doubt. For what is about your solution, I'm not able to have the same results as the mySQL implementation because I'm not able to filter duplicate records with `JOIN`.

Comment: Given that the tuple [`b.name`, `a.title`] should be unique in your source data (well, mostly), what are you expecting to be unique?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get a set of information in the same order that you specify the ID values. There is a hack that can convert a list into a table using XML and CROSS APPLY. This can be combined with the ROW_NUMBER function to generate your sort order. See the code below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNvarcharsFromXmlArray] 
(   
    @Strings xml = N'<ArrayOfStrings/>'
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber, Strings.String.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS String
    FROM          @Strings.nodes('/ArrayOfStrings/string/text()') AS Strings(String)
)
```

Which functions with the following structure:

```
<ArrayOfStrings>
    <string>myvalue1</string>
    <string>myvalue2</string>
</ArrayOfStrings>
```

It's also the same format .NET xml serializes string arrays.

If you want to pass a comma separated list, you can simply use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNvarcharsCSV] 
(   
    @CommaSeparatedStrings nvarchar(MAX) = N''
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
        DECLARE @Strings xml
        SET @Strings = CONVERT(xml, N'<ArrayOfStrings><string>' + REPLACE(@CommaSeperatedStrings, ',', N'</string><string>') + N'</string></ArrayOfStrings>')

    SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber, Strings.String.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS String
    FROM          @Strings.nodes('/ArrayOfStrings/string/text()') AS Strings(String)
)
```

This makes your query:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
INNER JOIN dbo.GetNvarcharsCSV(@name_ids) AS IDList ON users.ID = IDList.String
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Note that it's a pretty simple rewrite to make the function return a table of integers if that's what you need.

You can see [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) to get a better understanding of what you can do with XML in SQL queries. Also, see [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm a real noob in SQL, VBA and .NET so I had an hard time to fully understand your solution and I don't think I got it because I tried to implement it but it doesn't work. Anyway I've found a solution that is more comprehensible to me and I prefer to leverage on it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: As promised, I came back and updated the answer to be more complete. I hope it's clearer now that you can see the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a user-defined function that maintains the order, and then order by that column. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitList
(
    @List VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      [Rank],
      [Value] = CONVERT(INT, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Rank],
        CHARINDEX(',', @List + ',', [Rank]) - [Rank]))))
    FROM
    (
      SELECT TOP (8000) [Rank] = ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    ) AS n
    WHERE [Rank] <= LEN(@List)
      AND SUBSTRING(',' + @List, [Rank], 1) = ','
);
GO
```

Now your query can look something like this:

```
SELECT u.name 
  FROM dbo.users AS u 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SplitList($name_ids) AS s
  ON u.id = s.Value
  ORDER BY s.[Rank];
```

You may have to surround `$name_ids` with single quotes (`dbo.SplitList('$name_ids')`) depending on how the SQL statement is constructed. You may want to consider using a stored procedure instead of building this query in PHP.

You might also consider skipping MS-Access as a hopping point altogether. Why not just have PHP communicate directly with SQL Server?

Comment: Your solution uses `CHARINDEX` that is not available to me, is there an equivalent for it? I must use a MS Access database connected with ADODB because my hosting service requires an extra cost for handling SQL database directly

Comment: @Andrea3000 - if charindex isn't available, maybe you're not using sql server (Transact SQL).

Comment: Again I suggest using a stored procedure and calling the stored procedure from PHP directly. If you're trying to pass this query to Access, you will have a ridiculously hard time crafting a query that does what you want, can be parsed by MS-Access and executed by SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately, with my hosting plan I can't access SQL Server, I can only connect to the MS Access database and perform MS Access SQL query. Anyway I've found a working solution which allowed me to obtain the same behavior of FIND_IN_SET. Thank you for your help anyway!